# I want to make a login without input form

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a login without input form, just use a button that authenticates to the custom field firebase, help me

```
TextView var_text;
private DatabaseReference ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    var_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoText);
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("karyawan");



}
String phoneID;

public void btnLogin_Click(View view) {

    phoneID = phoneID.getBytes().toString();

    ref.child(phoneID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            karyawan karyawan = dataSnapshot.getValue(karyawan.class);
            if (phoneID.equals(karyawan.getPhoneID())){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login sukses", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Anda belum terdaftar" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3iby.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8fDe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want your login information stored on the mobile device? If so just store it as strings and pass those in when you login. Not secure obviously. Something like this:

You will also need to add the credentials to your firebase database. There are also some rules about email and pass words they have to be value e.g. email needs an @ with something after it like .com. And I think the passwords needs to be at least length 6.

```html
private void login(String email, String password) 
{
 String my_username = test;
 String my_password = test;
 
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(my_username, my_password)
 .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {//This is the logging in api
 @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
   if (task.isSuccessful()) //Logged in successfully to firebase
   {
     // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
     Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
     FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();//Identify who is logged in
     logged_in_user_string = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();//Store the logged in user's email address to be displayed
     //You are logged in here stare next activity
     

   }
   else
   {
     // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
     Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
     Log.d(TAG, "Login failed");
     
   }
  }
 });
}
```